# Custom UITableCell: Why delete icon appears on the content of the cell view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom cell in my tableview. **when uitable view is in the editing mode. the rounded delete icon appears on the content of the cell.**

How do I move the content to the right so to make place for the that little red rounded button.

In custom cell view layoutsubview should happen something. **which subview of cell view should i resize?**

thanks in advance

please take a look at my current code

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
 {
[super layoutSubviews];

CGFloat width = self.width - _productImage.right - 20.f;

if (self.accessoryView)
{
    width -= self.accessoryView.width;
}

_productName.width        = width;
_productDescription.width = width;
_productPrice.width       = width;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];

for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {


    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = self.contentView.frame;
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(40, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, newFrame.size.width, newFrame.size.height);
    }
    else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = self.contentView.frame;
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(40, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, newFrame.size.width, newFrame.size.height);
    }
    else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = self.contentView.frame;
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(40, self.contentView.frame.origin.y, newFrame.size.width, newFrame.size.height);
    }
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the ***[tableview.isEditing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)*** property.

If that is *YES*, then update the cell.contentView frame to *x-difference* otherwise use the default one.

Hope this is what you required.

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: where should i check this? in cell view? or tablview controller

Comment: for others i did it in custom cell : if self.isEditing in layoutsubviews then reposition the uielements. thanks for hint

Comment: M glad that it helps you... Can you please up vote the same.. Thanks in advance.. :)